# What's the keyboard shortcut to select the non-default button on a pop-up alert?

Tags: keyboard, uti

Look at the screenshot. I want to select the non-blue button with a keyboard shortcut. What is it?

[image]

Comment: I tried the spacebar and it didn't work for this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tab key to navigate the focus between buttons, and press the space bar when a button is selected.[image]

The effect is as above image.  When a blue box around a button, press the space bar, the button will be "pressed".

If you found that the focus cannot be set to the button, pen the Keyboard preference, and config it as following:
[image]

Comment: That looks like Lion. I'm using SL. And the tab does not work either.

Comment: Ok I just saw your edit. Working now.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without full access?

Answer (score 2):

[@kukoo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30660/whats-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-select-the-non-default-button-on-a-pop-up-alert/30662#30662) is right — also, for many pop-up dialogs, pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd><First letter in the button></kbd> works.

That means you could reach the "**U**se .csv" button by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

Comment: This isn't working for me. (On Mavericks beta, so I guess I can't complain.)

Comment: @Moshe Works for me on "real" Mavericks.